# Is it possible for me to get all my questions that have been deleted undeleted?

Tags: support

I have been banned due to many bad deleted questions. I was wondering if there was a way to undelete my bad questions to try to edit them and get them reopened.

Is this even possible to do? I know admins can view my deleted questions, just didn't know any further details.

Comment: I undeleted three of the four that I saw. The other one was unsalvageable, but these could possibly be edited into shape.

Comment: Thank you, @BradLarson. I edited all of them hoping to get them bumped/reopened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flag one of your non-deleted posts (on Stack Overflow), select "other", and explain in the textbox that you want your deleted posts undeleted so you can improve them. Then a moderator will do that for you.

[image]
[image]